# jQuery Auto Selection in a Select Options Form

Tags: jquery, html-select, transfer

I am managing 2 (multi) Select lists with options, where the left one (ListAllUsers) is collecting user names from a db query and the right one (SelectedUsers) is empty by default. Every time I click on a name in ListAllUsers it will transfer it in SelectedUsers where it will be submitted by the form. In order to submit the data from the SelectedUsers list, all the Options need to have the "selected" attribute. I have managed this to some extent, but I ran into one particular problem: When I try to remove all the users from the SelectedUsers back into ListAllUsers, I can't seem to remove the last user due to the fact that the "forceSelect" prevents me to click it for some reason and I can't figure why, as all the removed users also are selected by default in this list when being removed.

Here is an example:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id='ListAllUsers' class="form-control">
              
                    <option class="content" value="1">1</option>
                    <option class="content" value="2">2</option>
                    <option class="content" value="3">3</option>
                    <option class="content" value="4">4</option>
            
            </select>

<select name="user_id[]" multiple="multiple" id='SelectedUsers' class="form-control">

                </select>


(function () {
$("#ListAllUsers").change(function (e) 
    {
        let selectedOpts = $("#ListAllUsers option:selected");
        if (selectedOpts.length == 0) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $("#SelectedUsers").append($(selectedOpts).clone().prop('selected', true));
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
            e.preventDefault();
    });

$("#SelectedUsers").change(function (e) 
{
    let selectedOpts = $("#SelectedUsers option:selected");
    let forceSelect  = $("#SelectedUsers option");
    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $("#ListAllUsers").append($(selectedOpts).clone().prop('selected', false));
    $(forceSelect).prop('selected', true)
    $(selectedOpts).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer seems to have been easier than I thought. I just exchanged the "change" function for the "click" one and it worked out of the box! Also, the e.preventDefault() at the end is overkill, so that can go as well! Hope it helps someone who has a similar situation as mine!